# How to reference a static parameter from subclass at a super class static function?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, static

I have the following code:

```
class A {
    static printName = () => {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

class B extends A {}

A.printName(); //Prints 'A'
B.printName(); //Prints 'A' (I thought it would print 'B')
```

Why does `B.printName()` doesn't print 'B' instead of 'A'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a normal function, not an arrow function - arrow functions lose the binding to `this`:

```js
class A {
    static printName() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

class B extends A {}

A.printName();
B.printName();
```